# Collisions between UI elements in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, unity3d-gui

I am able to detect collision between UI components and a gameobject if my canvas is rendered in the world space. Here, I am trying to find collision between two UI elements (say UI buttons) when the canvas render mode is screen space overlay.

I added box collider components to my UI buttons and tried using OnCollisionEnter2D and OnTriggerEnter2D. But, the collision is not detected. Is there a way to detect the collision?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question does not require a code body. However, I have figured out a solution. TO both the UI elements, you need to:

- Attach a `rigidbody2d` component
- Attach a box collider component
- disable gravity
- enable the `isTrigger` checkbox.

Now in the script attached to one of the UI elements:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
{
    Debug.Log ("Triggered");
}
```

This would detect the collision.

Comment: Turning off the gravity is just to prevent the UI elements from falling down? Or is it necessary for the actual collision detection?

Comment: It is only to prevent the UI elements from falling down.

Comment: Man, I was using OnCollisionEnter and OnCollisionEnter2D, thanks for highlight we need to use OnTriggerEnter2D, it was the detail I was missing. Instead of change the gravity to zero I just made it kinematic, no need to ask the rigidbody to do any other calculation. But your solution worked just fine, thank you.